# MSAL B2C PasswordReset Flow causes "invalid grant" error

Tags: ios, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to build a Sign In / Sign Up - and Password Reset flow using the MSAL(1.1.7) library on iOS.

For the `B2C_1A_SignUpSignIn` policy everything seems to work fine. Tokens are received after the round trip to the browser.

When a user requests a reset, by tapping the "Forgot Password" in the webview:
I catch the `AADB2C90118` error code, as per the docs and start a new flow with an Authority that has a `B2C_1A_PasswordReset` policy.

```
let authority = try MSALB2CAuthority(url: authURL)
let config = MSALPublicClientApplicationConfig(clientId: AuthCredential.clientID.description,
                                            redirectUri: AuthCredential.redirectUri.description,
                                              authority: authority)
config.knownAuthorities = [authority]
            
let application = try MSALPublicClientApplication(configuration: config)
            
return application
```

This is all fine, reset flow, starts, can be finished and results in accessToken, and refreshToken.

**Now comes the problem**
These newly acquired tokens are only valid for the `B2C_1A_PasswordReset` policy, and when I get tokens silently, to use against our api, it happens with the `B2C_1A_SignUpSignIn` policy. This means that the first time I try to do a request that includes a call to `MSAL.getTokenSilently` I get this error:

```
MSALErrorDescriptionKey=User interaction is required, 
MSALOAuthErrorKey=invalid_grant,
NSUnderlyingError=0x6000018a5590 {
    UserInfo = { MSALErrorDescriptionKey=AADB2C90088: The provided grant has not been issued for this endpoint. 
    Actual Value : B2C_1A_SignUpSignIn and Expected Value : B2C_1A_PasswordReset,
    MSALOAuthErrorKey=invalid_grant,
    MSALInternalErrorCodeKey=-42004 
    }
}
```

The error seems fairly clear, if my understanding is correct at least, there is no user, only an accessToken and refreshToken linked to the `B2C_1A_PasswordReset` policy. And a manual user login is required.

**Am I supposed to start a manual login flow for the user now?**

The iOS forgot password flow would then be almost silly:

1. Tap account (ask for tokenInteractively with `B2C_1A_SignUpSignIn` policy)
2. iOS prompt to allow opening the webview in safari
3. users taps "forgot password" in webview
4. redirected back to app that catches the error code (`AADB2C90118`)
5. start a tokenInteractively with a policy of `B2C_1A_PasswordReset`
6. iOS prompt to allow opening the webview in safari
7. User jumps through all the reset password hoops
8. redirected back to app with an accessToken and refreshToken (that I can't use for anything)
9. start a tokenInteractively with a policy of `B2C_1A_SignUpSignIn`
10. iOS prompt to allow opening the webview in safari
11. user signs in with new credentials
12. redirected back to app with an accessToken and refreshToken (that I **CAN** use)

**Android** does not impose the prompt to open the browser and for my colleague developing that flow, the user is logged in after a password reset, it seems a login is happening successfully in the background.

I haven't been able to find an example of a password reset flow in the docs for iOS. There are examples for the other platforms.

**Can I structure this in a different way to get a better flow?**

**We have access to the backend, is there something we can do there?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Policies and the tokens retrieved in their context are linked. There could be different permissions and flows associated with different policies, so from the MSAL/apps perspective they might as well be different backends.

Ok, a better flow is to make sure that when using `getTokenSilently` you must also make sure to use the tokens matching the policy the token were retrieved with.

In all the MSAL examples I found online this had not been an issue because they do it directly in the ViewController and hold on to a reference to the `application` object.
I instead set it up each time I need it like this:

```
let authority = try MSALB2CAuthority(url: authURL)
let config = MSALPublicClientApplicationConfig(clientId: AuthCredential.clientID.description,
                                            redirectUri: AuthCredential.redirectUri.description,
                                              authority: authority)
config.knownAuthorities = [authority]
            
let application = try MSALPublicClientApplication(configuration: config)
```

with the authority I need for a particular task. so, in my case, when the user needed a password reset I would change the authority, go to the webview and reset the password, get the tokens back, they're automatically put into MSAL. Now when I call `getTokenSilently` I would use the SignInSignUp policy but the tokens in MSAL would be linked to the password reset policy => "invalid grant"

What I did to fix it, as I still think the pattern of instantiating an `MSALPublicClientApplication` only when you need it is much nicer, as this is linked to various API calls different places in the app and not just in one ViewController, was to make an extension on `MSALPublicClientApplication` with an application class method that takes the Policy from the last successful `getTokenSilently` or `getTokenInteractively` and always use that to construct an application object.

```
class func application() -> MSALPublicClientApplication? {
    do {
        let authURLString = UserDefaults.getMSALPolicyKey() ?? AuthCredential.signInAuthority.description
        let authURL = URL(string: authURLString)!
        let authority = try MSALB2CAuthority(url: authURL)
        
        let config = MSALPublicClientApplicationConfig(clientId: AuthCredential.clientID.description,
                                                       redirectUri: AuthCredential.redirectUri.description,
                                                       authority: authority)
        config.knownAuthorities = [authority]
        
        let application = try MSALPublicClientApplication(configuration: config)
        
        return application
        
    } catch {
        // catch and log error
        return nil
    }
}
```

and the policy should be saved like this:

```
application.acquireTokenSilent(with: silentParameters) { (result, error) in
    guard let result = result, let key = result.account.identifier, error == nil else {
    // Error handling
    UserDefaults.clearMSALPolicies() // clear policies so we default to standard policy 
        }
        
        completion(.failure(nsError))
    }
    // get policy directly from result
    UserDefaults.setMSALPolicyKey(key: result.authority.url.absoluteString)
    completion(.success(result.accessToken))
}
```

This cuts the password reset flow list in the question back down to 7 steps and the user is logged in.

On Android it actually didn't work, we just had fairly long lived tokens so the error didn't show up there until much later when the token with the password reset policy expired and the client tried to refresh it using the SignInSignOut policy => "invalid grant".